# Python and OpenCV - Algorithm to have a better result for lane detection

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv

I am trying to detect lane from the detected edges of an image/video, and apply Hough Transform to it. Right now, I am trying to compare the result of the Hough Transform and the Probabilistic Hough Transform.

So, this is my result. (The red lines is the result from the Probabilistic Hough Transform while the green lines is from the normal Hough Transform).
[image]

First, I have determined the Region of Interest (ROI) and have done many processes on it to get its result.
[image]

I already do some math so that only certain lines are detected by the Probabilistic Hough Transform and the Hough Transform (like defining the angle of the wanted line).

**Hough Transform:**

As you can see, I need to lower the threshold for the Hough Transform so that the shorter road's lane (the right side) can be detected too. But this resulting of many unwanted lines being detected, especially on the left side of the road.

One way of getting around of this, I am thinking of allowing only just one line being detected in a range of angle (for the left and right lane of the road).

For example, for a range of angle from 0 to 90 degrees, just detect the line with the highest vote (for the left lane), and from 90 to 180 degrees, also just detect the line with the highest vote (for the right lane). But I don't know if this is the best choice and what kind of unpredictable consequences can occur (especially if I use this method on videos.)

**Probabilistic Hough Transform:**

On the other hand, I am really into the Probabilistic Hough Transform since I think it is more robust. The problem is, it is a little bit unpredictable (at least for me), and I need a way to make a better one line out of many lines outputted by the Probabilistic Hough Transform. One way of this that I can think of is by calculating its gradient, and make something out of it.

So, I need to know if anyone have any good ideas/algorithms that I can try to implement. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i like your idea, maybe you want to do a linear regression on the red lines (you could split it up into positive and negative gradients first to separate the left and right edges). maybe if you give this a go and if you get stuck you could sharpen up your question a bit by providing some sample output from the probabilistic transform and show what you've tried

Comment: @maxymoo Thanks for your words! Really does motivate me. But since I am kind of chasing deadline right now, I will need to try to figure out this technique another time. In the meantime, maybe I'll try to apply Hough Transform on the line I've got from the Probabilistic Hough Transform. I do think there is a better way than this though.

Comment: i don't think that will work ... isn't the hough transform like a filter ? i.e. it can only reduce the image, not fill in the gaps ?

Comment: @maxymoo It works. First, I used the probabilistic to detect lanes. It gives a quite good result because it managed to catch the short lane too. Then, I draw the lines by the probabilistic on another canvas (numpy array) and then, apply normal hough on the canvas. From there, I managed to catch the shorter lane. Quite a work around, but I do think there is a more sophisticated way of solving this.